# Return the dates between two datetime with particular format in String C#

Tags: c#, html, date, datetime, difference

I have 2 datetime format as departure date and arrival date, such as 25/04/2014 as a departure and 22/04/2014 as an arrival, now I wish to return the dates between those two as following: 22/04/2014|23/04/2014|24/04/2014|25/04/2014 in C#, do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Just do this in a while loop, and add a day in each iteration.

Comment: Just concatenate the dates with "|".

Comment: `25/04/2014 as a departure and 22/04/2014 as an arrival` You have a Tardis? ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 4, 22);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 4, 25);
var sb = new StringBuilder();
while (startDate <= endDate)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("|{0}", startDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().Substring(1));
```

See it in [action](http://ideone.com/4foZ2L)

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid to type a loop using Linq

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
DateTime arrival = new DateTime(2014,4,22);
DateTime departure = new DateTime(2014,4,25);
int days = Convert.ToInt32((departure - arrival).TotalDays);

var rng = Enumerable.Range(0,days+1).ToList();
rng.ForEach(r => sb.Append(arrival.AddDays(r).ToShortDateString() + "|"));
sb.Length--;
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Like:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 25);
var endDate = new DateTime(2014, 04, 29);

var currentDate = startDate;
while (currentDate <= endDate)
{
       Console.WriteLine(currentDate);
       currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

...but with proper formatting, but this would be view-logic.

Answer (score 0):

Voilà:

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2014, 4, 24);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2014, 4, 22);

        DateTime current = start < end ? start : end;
        DateTime stop = start < end ? end : start;

        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

        while (current <= stop)
        {
            dates.Add(current);
            current = current.AddDays(1);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DateTime dt in dates)
        {
            if (sb.Length > 0)
                sb.Append("|");

            sb.Append(dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```